filter by laravel inertia vue 3
I need to remove or hide query params when I filter data.
const filterCategory = useForm({ categories: "" });
const filterUnit = useForm({ unit: "" });

watch(
    () => filterCategory.categories,
    () => {
        const params = { categories: filterCategory.categories };
        filterCategory.get(route("products.index", params), {
            preserveScroll: true,
            onStart: () => rmQueryParams(),
            onSuccess: () => rmQueryParams(),
        });
    }
);

watch(
    () => filterUnit.unit,
    () => {
        const params = { unit: filterUnit.unit };
        filterUnit.get(route("products.index", params), {
            preserveScroll: true,
            onBefore: () => rmQueryParams(),
            onProgress: () => rmQueryParams(),
            onSuccess: () => rmQueryParams(),
        });
    }
);

content of the function rmQueryParams()
export const rmQueryParams = () => {
    window.history.replaceState(
        {},
        document.title,
        window.location.pathname,
        window.location.search
    );
};


before
http://blog.zik/products?categories=9bfbca82-3cba-43b8-be60-759d8736c085
after
http://blog.zik/products


what does this have to do with laravel tag? You don't have nothing here in laravel  please change this.

i'm using laravel inertia vue

Would you please share little more detail that isn't it working fine or getting error?

I just want to find another alternative.
